# How can I remove clouds' borders on Sentinel-2 images?

Tags: python, gdal, sentinel-2

I have to replace area with clouds from another image without clouds. So I have a problem when I remove clouds from my mask I have borders of clouds. I use Sentinel-2 SLC image. For begin I open my mask of scene classification(SLC) in 'jp2' formats. Then I resize my image to format my composites(10980x10980). I use ReadAsArray for both files. Then, where mask have labels with clouds and shadows I set 0 and works with arrays:

```
raster_composite1[:, mask_slc1 == 0] = raster_composite2[:, mask_slc1 == 0]#i have 4 bands
```

Input image:

[image]

In output I have image:

[image]

So, how can I remove those white borders ?

Comment: You could expand the areas covered with clouds and then remove those areas. But you will still have to cope with shadows.

Comment: @Alešinar Could you give me some advice how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cloud mask provided by Sentinel2 L2A, from Sen2cor software, is not dilated. You could try to dilate it using scipy.ndimage.dilate in python. That would increase the surface of detected clouds by a given buffer (for instance 200m).

The trouble is that the L2A scene classification from Sen2cor also has plenty of false clouds on towns and buildings, which, once dilated could make large regions disappear.

Other cloud mask solutions exist that do not have this issue:

[Baetens, L.; Desjardins, C.; Hagolle, O. Validation of Copernicus Sentinel-2 Cloud Masks Obtained from MAJA, Sen2Cor, and FMask Processors Using Reference Cloud Masks Generated with a Supervised Active Learning Procedure. Remote Sens. 2019, 11, 433.](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/11/4/433)